# Lubuntu 18.10, what the heck is this screen?

Tags: lubuntu

I installed Lubuntu 18.10 overwriting everything on the drive. When the installation finished, I rebooted and logged in.  I walked away for some time and when I came back this image was on the screen.  [image]  Anyone know what it is or means?

Hitting a key cleared it and I saw the regular desk top and it seemed fully functional.  The second time it happened I took a picture (figuring the printscreen key might clear the screen rather than capture it.)  The vertical lines were moving in a wave pattern (the crooked vertical lines in the pic.)  The flame pictured over the monitor didn't give me a good feeling.

At all other times since, leaving Lubuntu sit just brings up the default screen saver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never thought of it being an actual screen saver.  It looks like one called "distort".

I don't understand how a screen saver that looks like the effects of a GPU overheating  with a flame on top of a monitor was chosen as a good screen saver.  Oh well, they don't consult me on these things :)

Comment: I can't vote on my own post.  I like my answer since it names the screen saver I saw.  Thanks for sending me in the correct direction.

Comment: *You can 'accept' your own answer* (make the grey tick icon green). It can help other users by indicating, that the question has an answer, that is considered good by the OP (the person who asked the question).